# Call a JavaScript function depending on the value of a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript

I am passing a variable via the URL as `var=5` to `urlrun.php` (like `urlrun.php?var=5`). There is a JavaScript function called `testrun` in `urlrun.php`.

**Is there a way to call that JavaScript function depending on the value of that variable (`var`) passed through the URL?**

For example, `if($_GET['var']==5)`, I need to call that JavaScript function.

Answer (score 4):

Put this somewhere:

```
<?php if($_GET['var'] == 5) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        testrun();
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @look4php: It should. Try replacing the contents of `testrun` with a simple `alert("testrun called");` and see if it works.

Comment: you should try `if(intval($_GET['var']) == 5)`